# how to integrate yatra xml soap APi in php

Tags: php, xml, api, soap

I want to integrate flight API of "yatra". I have xml that we need to to get the result. I have written the following code inside api folder in index.php file, but it keeps reloading the page

```
hi i am trying to integrate the travel API. i am using following POS code:-
```

`$xml='<POS xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
                    <Source AgentSine="" PseudoCityCode="NPCK" TerminalID="1"><RequestorID ID="AFFILIATE"/>
                    </Source>
                    <YatraRequests>
                        <YatraRequest DoNotHitCache="true" DoNotCache="false" RequestType="SR" AffiliateID="TRAVELPARTNER" MidOfficeAgentID="7499"        YatraRequestTypeCode=”SMPA”/>
                    </YatraRequests>
                </POS>';`

```
    `$url = "http://localhost/api/index.php";
    //setting the curl parameters.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"xmlRequest=" . $xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 900);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($data); die;
    //convert the XML result into array
    $array_data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($data)), true);
```

please let me know if I am missing something. above is POS node.The POS element node is common for all the requests send to Yatra Application Framework.